# Symfony2 and jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, symfony, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have created a web application with Symfony2, and now I want to create a mobile application that implements some features that the web app also does.

I don't know how to start implementing it. Can I reuse something I have already made for in-web app? Do I have to create a new bundle?

I have searched on the web and googled, but I have not found the answer for all these questions.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using jQuery mobile because you are creating a web app or a native application to the device?

Comment: I don't understand your question.. sorry. I would like to use jQuery mobile, it seems to be easy. I have also downloaded MobileDetecBundle, which seems to be useful to detect the device from which the user is getting into the application. I think I can integrate the mobile app in my pc application, and just check the devide in order to redirect to a correct view , depending on the device.

Comment: the difference is whether you are creating a website that is optimized for mobile, or a standalone app, in which case the templates and assets on the server (symfony project) are irrelevant.

Comment: I want to use the app I have done for the web to do the mobile part. However, it is not necessary that all the information and views in the pc app are in the mobile app. I hope you understand my question.

Comment: I'm going to assume then you are building a website accessible by both desktop and mobile, in which case responsive design may be your best option, take a look at: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: ok, thanks, I am going to take a look at it. Do you know if it is compatible with Symfony2?

Comment: its front end stuff, so its completely separate from symfony, as in symfony doesn't care about the front end so its fair game.

Comment: well, I have taken a look at it, but I don't want to use the same views in both. I want to use jQuery for mobile devices views. My questions is... how to do that in my symfony2 project?

Comment: Couple of ways; override the template listener so you can use the same controllers but different templates https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/TemplateListener.php, or redirect to a mobile path and re-create the controllers.  I prefer the former solution, but you wont get a full answer for it here, try symfony irc.

Comment: I think I am going to create a new bundle called MobileBundle, because the user won't have all the functionality in the mobile as in the web. I will use the entities in the bundles I already have, but I will create new Controller and Views. I will detect if the user is accessing from a mobile in my indexAction, and redirect the user to app or to mobile controller. Do you think is it a good idea? Any help to start doing that?